# How to export on a text file the content of all mails in queue?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I'm noticing an anomalous activity for postfix and I want to check the outgoing mails

`mailq` shows a bunch of mails in queue with their id without any info on their specific body content to give me a clear idea of what is generating these outgoing mails

also

```
postcat -q id
```

it's useless because the suspicious mails and related ids are continuously processed and removed from queue, so when I perform the check on some id, it is no longer valid.

How could I export  on a text file the content of all mails in queue?

Answer (score 0):

Following script will help you to store all the mail contents to a file named "mail_contents.txt"

```
#!/bin/bash
for id in $(postqueue -p | awk '$7 ~/@/ { print $1 }' | awk -F "*" '{print $1}'); do postcat -q $id; done > mail_contents.txt
```

Comment: it seems `postcat -q` it does nothing without an id passed

Comment: @AndreaF sorry, you are correct. i have edited my answer and provided you with bash script. please check and let me know the result.

Comment: thanks for reply, but this is similar to one of my attemts, seems this method fails at first id that is no longer valid(ids are continuously processed and removed as I have said), it is needed a way to export them in bulk regardlesss the id (maybe some way to export them directly from the file used to temporary store them??)